# Any other options to get my All-In-One PC touchscreen to work with windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, display

I have a Sony vaio All-in-one touchscreen that had windows 7 installed. I originally had done an "upgrade" to windows 8 and the touchscreen worked fine. My HDD was starting to fail though so I just bought a full version of windows 8 and installed it on a new SSD.

Ever since this the only way I can get the touchscreen to work is by going into device manager and uninstalling  "Intel(R) HD Graphics" and then restarting the computer. I have to do this every time I restart the PC or the touchscreen doesn't work.

Any ideas on an easier workaround?

Comment: Are there any updated drivers from Sony that might fix this?

Comment: These are the Sony drivers for my PC that Sony offers. I have tried installing some of them that I thought could even be remotely related to my touchscreen but have had no luck. They are intended for windows 7 though. Any thoughts would be appreciated. http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCJ113FX&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab

Comment: Can you uninstall the Intel HD Graphics driver from the management console and tick to delete the driver files for it too (E.g. http://www.orison.biz/blogs/chall3ng3r/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ms-network-2.jpg)... can you then install the ORIGINAL drivers as listed on that support page you kindly posted up? - If that works after restarting (i.e. the touchscreen works straight away) then make sure you never update the graphics driver through Windows update!

Comment: Idk if this would effect the factory driver or not but I did upgrade the cpu from the factory i3 to an i7 that is in the same class but this was after I had this problem. Also whenever I "unistall" this driver with the way I've been fixing this issue the screen goes black until I restart the PC. So if I attempted the method you mentioned above would it just make the screen go black after the first step?

Comment: *hopefully* not... Windows should be able to display using a minimal "fallback" resolution - something like 800x600 - until you install drivers to improve the resolution.

Comment: completely remove them from the device manger and check "Delete Driver software". Then run windows update (make sure you are able to receive "recommended" updates as well) and install the graphics driver from there. see if that helps. post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "work around" I have found for this is to go to "device manager" and uninstall "Intel(R) HD Graphics" driver under Display adapters. This causes the screen to go black, but pushing (not holding) the power button lets the system restart and then the touchscreen works. I had to do this every time but here lately it every once in awhile works without this "workaround". But I have always been able to fix it by doing the above steps.